# Upgraded to package that was subsequently removed from repo...what to do?

Tags: 14.04, repository, synaptic

I noticed in Synaptic Package Manager that the version of `udisks2` I have is "local" so I was trying to figure out what happened there.  It looks like on June 17th I picked up version `udisks2 (2.1.3-1ubuntu0.2)` through the normal update process, but according to [this page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/proposed/udisks2) that version was later deleted from the repos.

What's the safest way for me to remove this apparently flawed package from my system?  And why doesn't this situation get handled automatically?

Comment: That version was in the "proposed" repo.  Using the "proposed" repository can sometimes cause issues like this but the releases are more "bleeding edge" so it's kind of a tradeoff. It doesn't get handled automatically because apt favors and tries to always install the newest version. In this case, the newest version is older than the installed version so it isn't considered the newest. You can set a priority for each repo so that apt will favor a certain repo over another but then the proposed packages would only install if explicitly called.

Comment: I didn't do anything special, just performed a normal `apt-get-update` and `apt-get-upgrade`.

Comment: you don't need to do anything special, the problem occoured because you have the "proposed" repo enabled. You can disable this repo in synaptic or software-center, or you can manually edit or comment the proposed repo out of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: This explains how to set the priority for this repo so that stuff isn't installed automatically, however, packages will still be available in case you want a newer version. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package itself was not deleted from the [officially Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=udisks2&searchon=names). Maybe the version `2.1.3-1ubuntu0.2`, but that's unusual.

And as you said in the comments:

> As @mchid mentions above, somehow I had 'proposed' changes enabled.
>   When I took this off, a whole bunch of other packages got moved to
>   local. And this explains so much, like why this PC was getting kernels
>   before my the other ones.

---

Therefore force a downgrade

```
sudo apt-get install udisks2=2.1.3-1ubuntu0.1
```

or with `synaptic`

1. Select the package in synaptic
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to select a specific version
3. Select the latest version for `trusty-updates`
4. Apply the changes

Comment: Yes, it looks like a new version was moved in, I upgraded, and then it was moved out.  Timing is everything! :(  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: As @mchid mentions above, somehow I had 'proposed' changes enabled.  When I took this off, a whole bunch of other packages got moved to local.  And this explains so much, like why this PC was getting kernels before my the other ones.  I really appreciate the info from both of you.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have improved the answer with your information. Thx =)